# ERROR: "docker buildx build" requires exactly 1 argument. - Azure Devops Pipeline

Tags: node.js, docker, azure-devops

I keep getting this error in my Azure Devops Pipeline when trying to build the docker image:

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 \
                --label version=$(cat package.json | jq -r '.version') \
                --label version=$(cat package.json | jq -r '.version' | cut -d '.' -f 1,2) \
                --label version=$(cat package.json | jq -r '.version' | cut -d '.' -f 1) \
                --label $commit \
                --build-arg ARG1=$(ARG1) \
                --build-arg ARG2=$(ARG2) \
                -t ***.azurecr.io/$(image):$commit \
                -t ***.azurecr.io/$(image):latest \
                --push \
                .
```

`ERROR: "docker buildx build" requires exactly 1 argument.`

The Dockerfile is located in the root source code directory. Locally, I can build the docker image. Any help what I might be overlooking is very much appreciated.

I did try to specify dockerfile, didn't help:

`docker buildx build -f ./Dockerfile ...`

`ls` in the pipeline showed me that I actually am in the right directory with the dockerfile.

Comment: My first step for debugging issues like this is often to put `echo` at the front of the command and see what comes out.  Note that you're not quoting any of the command substitutions or variable expansions, which can result in unexpected things creeping into the command.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DavidMaze, quotation of the vars did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quotation of variables fixes it:

`--build-arg ARG1="$(ARG1)"`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).